# What might this ghcjs-boot error mean?

Tags: nix, ghcjs

I'm trying to try out GHCJS, and I get this error during ghcjs-boot:

(https://gist.github.com/Wizek/e4a73c6e9542a119ddd6)

```
➜  ghcjs-test  load-env-ghc7103 ghcjs-boot     
env-ghc7103 loaded
program ghcjs found at ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs
program ghcjs-pkg found at ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg
program ghcjs-run found at ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-run
program ghc found at /nix/store/la1c1y85mwnrzvwsqimz2g5abpz3529p-ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc
program ghc-pkg found at /nix/store/la1c1y85mwnrzvwsqimz2g5abpz3529p-ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc-pkg
program cabal found at /nix/store/dazafgbrb505srvsjimdszjsyvdhks88-cabal-install-1.22.7.0/bin/cabal
program node found at /home/wizek/.nix-profile/bin/node
program haddock-ghcjs found at ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/haddock-ghcjs
program git found at /usr/bin/git
program alex found at /nix/store/cmaibhlj51pzq4pzx4xi5w7kdp1igmbx-alex-3.1.6/bin/alex
program happy found at /nix/store/naivzhc373by8ayvwm6m1wzhygm7x6ka-happy-1.19.5/bin/happy
program tar found at /nix/store/60zf1xjmhwbf4g42724wrrj6ydy45cch-gnutar-1.28/bin/tar
program cpp found at /usr/bin/cpp
program bash found at /nix/store/fx1kaw6faw8vmpwbhmlhl4agxgb110yw-bash-4.3-p42/bin/bash
program autoreconf NOT found, searched for autoreconf
program make found at /nix/store/zym9b3asfqcyhllrz2r8lzh6ir62ll1s-gnumake-4.1/bin/make
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [node]: /home/wizek/.nix-profile/bin/node "--version"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [cabal]: /nix/store/dazafgbrb505srvsjimdszjsyvdhks88-cabal-install-1.22.7.0/bin/cabal "--numeric-version"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs-pkg]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg "--numeric-ghc-version"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs-pkg]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg "--numeric-ghcjs-version"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghc]: /nix/store/la1c1y85mwnrzvwsqimz2g5abpz3529p-ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc "--numeric-version"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs "--numeric-ghc-version"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs "--numeric-version"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [cabal]: /nix/store/dazafgbrb505srvsjimdszjsyvdhks88-cabal-install-1.22.7.0/bin/cabal "install" "--help"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghc]: /nix/store/la1c1y85mwnrzvwsqimz2g5abpz3529p-ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc "-e" "either error id (Text.Read.readEither \"GHCJS\" :: Either String Distribution.Simple.CompilerFlavor)"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghc]: /nix/store/la1c1y85mwnrzvwsqimz2g5abpz3529p-ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc "--print-libdir"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs "--ghcjs-booting-print" "--print-libdir"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs "--ghcjs-booting-print" "--print-topdir"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs "--ghcjs-booting-print" "--print-global-db"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs "--ghcjs-booting-print" "--print-user-db-dir"
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs "--ghcjs-booting-print" "--print-native-too"


===========================================================================

   Boot libraries installation for GHCJS

===========================================================================

   ghcjs-boot will install the libraries and runtime system for GHCJS


  boot program
  ------------

   ghcjs-boot program version   0.2.0                                                                                                                                             
                file location   /media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test/.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-boot-0.2.0-7.10.3                                
                last modified   2016-01-08 20:07:48 UTC                                                                                                                           

     using configuration file   /media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test/.cabal-sandbox/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/ghcjs-0.2.0/lib/etc/boot.yaml
            current directory   /media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test                                                                           

  boot configuration
  ------------------

     installation directory   /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs                          
          global package DB   /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs/package.conf.d           
   user package DB location   /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3                                

              GHCJS version   0.2.0                                                                       
           program location   ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs                                                  
               library path   /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs                          
              last modified   2016-01-08 20:07:47 UTC                                                     

                GHC version   7.10.3                                                                      
                   location   /nix/store/la1c1y85mwnrzvwsqimz2g5abpz3529p-ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc              
               library path   /nix/store/la1c1y85mwnrzvwsqimz2g5abpz3529p-ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3       

      cabal-install version   1.22.7.0                                                                    
                   location   /nix/store/dazafgbrb505srvsjimdszjsyvdhks88-cabal-install-1.22.7.0/bin/cabal

          ghcjs-pkg version   0.2.0                                                                       
                   location   ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg                                              

                 quick boot   No                                                                          
           clean tree first   No                                                                          
           development boot   No                                                                          
                 native too   No                                                                          

  packages
  --------

   stage 1a

   - ./boot/array
   - ./boot/base
   - ./boot/binary
   - ./boot/bytestring
   - ./boot/containers
   - ./boot/deepseq
   - ./boot/integer-gmp
   - ./boot/pretty
   - ./boot/primitive
   - ./boot/template-haskell
   - ./boot/transformers

   ghcjs-prim:  ../ghcjs-prim

   stage 1b

   - ./boot/directory
   - ./boot/filepath
   - ./boot/old-locale
   - ./boot/process
   - ./boot/time
   - ./boot/unix

   Cabal:  ./boot/cabal/Cabal

   stage 2

   - ./boot/async
   - ./boot/aeson
   - ./boot/attoparsec
   - ./boot/case-insensitive
   - ./boot/dlist
   - ./boot/extensible-exceptions
   - ./boot/hashable
   - ./boot/mtl
   - ./boot/old-time
   - ./boot/parallel
   - ./boot/scientific
   - ./boot/stm
   - ./boot/syb
   - ./boot/text
   - ./boot/unordered-containers
   - ./boot/vector
   - ./ghcjs/ghcjs-base




===========================================================================

   Configured programs

===========================================================================

   program         version    location                                                                    

   ghcjs           0.2.0      ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs                                                  
   ghcjs-pkg       0.2.0      ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg                                              
   ghcjs-run       -          ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-run                                              
   ghc             7.10.3     /nix/store/la1c1y85mwnrzvwsqimz2g5abpz3529p-ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc              
   ghc-pkg         -          /nix/store/la1c1y85mwnrzvwsqimz2g5abpz3529p-ghc-7.10.3/bin/ghc-pkg          
   cabal           1.22.7.0   /nix/store/dazafgbrb505srvsjimdszjsyvdhks88-cabal-install-1.22.7.0/bin/cabal
   node            v0.10.41   /home/wizek/.nix-profile/bin/node                                           
   haddock-ghcjs   -          ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/haddock-ghcjs                                          
   git             -          /usr/bin/git                                                                
   alex            -          /nix/store/cmaibhlj51pzq4pzx4xi5w7kdp1igmbx-alex-3.1.6/bin/alex             
   happy           -          /nix/store/naivzhc373by8ayvwm6m1wzhygm7x6ka-happy-1.19.5/bin/happy          
   tar             -          /nix/store/60zf1xjmhwbf4g42724wrrj6ydy45cch-gnutar-1.28/bin/tar             
   cpp             -          /usr/bin/cpp                                                                
   bash            -          /nix/store/fx1kaw6faw8vmpwbhmlhl4agxgb110yw-bash-4.3-p42/bin/bash           
   autoreconf      -          <not found>                                                                 
   make            -          /nix/store/zym9b3asfqcyhllrz2r8lzh6ir62ll1s-gnumake-4.1/bin/make            




===========================================================================

   Installation sources

===========================================================================

       shims (runtime system)                                                                                                                                                       
                                /media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test/.cabal-sandbox/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/ghcjs-0.2.0/lib/shims          
                                /media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test/.cabal-sandbox/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/ghcjs-0.2.0/lib/cache/shims.tar

               boot libraries                                                                                                                                                       
                                /media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test/.cabal-sandbox/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/ghcjs-0.2.0/lib/ghcjs-boot     
                                /media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test/.cabal-sandbox/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/ghcjs-0.2.0/lib/cache/boot.tar 

                   test suite                                                                                                                                                       
                                /media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test/.cabal-sandbox/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/ghcjs-0.2.0/test               
                                /media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test/.cabal-sandbox/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/ghcjs-0.2.0/lib/cache/test.tar 

          configuration files                                                                                                                                                       
                                /media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test/.cabal-sandbox/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/ghcjs-0.2.0/lib/etc            

                documentation                                                                                                                                                       
                                /media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test/.cabal-sandbox/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3/ghcjs-0.2.0/doc                

   bootstrap GHC library path                                                                                                                                                       
                                /nix/store/la1c1y85mwnrzvwsqimz2g5abpz3529p-ghc-7.10.3/lib/ghc-7.10.3                                                                               

/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ rm_f /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs/ghcjs_boot.completed
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs$ preparing release boot tree
ghcjs-boot tree already installed
shims tree already installed
creating package databases
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ rm_rf /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs/package.conf.d
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ mkdir_p /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs/package.conf.d
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs-pkg]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg "init" "/home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs/package.conf.d"
./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg init /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs/package.conf.d
ghcjs-pkg-0.2.0-7.10.3: cannot create: /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs/package.conf.d already exists
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs-pkg]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg "recache" "--global"
./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg recache --global
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ rm_f /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/package.conf
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ rm_rf /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/package.conf.d
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ mkdir_p /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/package.conf.d
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs-pkg]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg "init" "/home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/package.conf.d"
./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg init /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/package.conf.d
ghcjs-pkg-0.2.0-7.10.3: cannot create: /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/package.conf.d already exists
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ [ghcjs-pkg]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg "recache" "--user"
./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg recache --user
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/ghcjs-test$ rm_rf /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/cache
installing RTS
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs/ghcjs-boot$ writing /home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs/package.conf.d/builtin_rts.conf
/media/wizek/31fde2c4-95a3-499e-9e05-2999f59a1469/home/wizek/.ghcjs/x86_64-linux-0.2.0-7.10.3/ghcjs/ghcjs-boot$ [ghcjs-pkg]: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg "recache" "--global" "--no-user-package-db"
./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg recache --global --no-user-package-db
ghcjs-boot: ./.cabal-sandbox/bin/ghcjs-pkg: createProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Nix was used to install GHC and a compatible Node.js, but I am not sure if this error is related to Nix or not.

1. Has anyone seen this error before?
2. Or any idea what might be going wrong?
3. Or any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: GHCJS needs to be installed globally and as `ghcjs-boot` doesn't work if it is run from a cabal sandbox it seems.